# Received a ServerHelloDone handshake message while expecting [CertificateRequest]

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, deno

I'm getting this error in fetch with Deno:

```
Received a ServerHelloDone handshake message while expecting [CertificateRequest]
```

I'm hitting a web api I don't control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/14494), it’s a bug in [one of Deno's upstream rust dependencies](https://github.com/rustls/rustls/issues/1012) which has already been patched, but not yet released.

Comment: Would this effect Deno since its written in Rust?

Comment: @chovy Yes, I clarified the phrasing in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I asked in discord and someone said they are working on it.